# Getting numeric range error in drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I am getting the following error in drupal while adding a content

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range`

Amazingly this error happens on only 1 computer and all other computers are adding the content very fine. I defined the column with INT so there is no chance of mistake from database side. Kindly help me in this matter.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of range exceeding, in other words drupal is not just counting the digits, it is also calculating the digits that the must not exceed 99999999 in an integer datatype. Hope this helps.